# ASP:Literal not within context when placed in ItemTemplate of Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page that is behaving differently than its peers and I can't seem to find out why.

Sadly I cannot post a lot of code for business reasons, and I know that this will limit users' ability to assist.

I have one page where I have an  with a hidden  and a checkbox and other unimportant things.

Something like:

```
<asp:Repeater id="GoodRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="GoodRepeater_OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal id="litHappyLiteral" runat="server" />
    <!-- Other junk that doesn't matter -->
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On ANOTHER page however, I have the same setup, but for some reason whenever I put an  inside the ItemTemplate, it drops out of my context and can no longer be reached by the code-behind. Ex:

```
<asp:Repeater id="RepeaterThatMakesMeSad" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterThatMakesMeSad_OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal id="litSadLiteral" runat="server" />
    <!-- Other junk that doesn't matter -->
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On the first page, litHappyLiteral is reachable by the code-behind, but on the other one litSadLiteral is not.

Any ideas?
Using asp.net 3.5.

Here's as much of my codebehind as I can share:

```
protected void RepeaterThatMakesMeSad_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
// Logging junk
// Guard clauses
try {
  XmlNode myItem = (e.Item.DataItem as XmlNode);

  if(myItem != null) {
   litSadLiteral.Text = "SADNESS.";
  } // End if
 } // end try
} // method
```

Under these conditions, "litSadLiteral" does not exist in the current context.

---

I figured out what I was doing wrong (see answer below), but if someone is still willing to explain WHY a literal drops out of the reachable context as soon as it's placed within the confines of an ItemTemplate of a Repeater, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: can u share your code behind ?

Comment: Is RepeaterThatMakesMeSad accessible? Are you using master pages?

Comment: Is RepeaterThatMakesMeSad accessible? - Yes.
Using master pages? - Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what was going on.

In my 'working' example, I didn't directly reach my literal.  I 'went searching' first.

In the working one, I didn't just have:

```
litHappyLiteral.Text = "Happy!";
```

I actually had:

```
Literal litHappyLiteral = (e.Item.FindControl("litHappyLiteral") as Literal);
if(litHappyLiteral != null) {
  litHappyLiteral.Text = "Happy!";
}
```

Now that I'm doing that on the other page everything is working.
Sorry for taking up everyone's time.

I don't know the process here for sure, should I delete this question or leave it up in case this blunder/solution could help someone in the future?